# How to skip to next in javascript in a for-in with a while inside?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, for-in-loop

I have a short javascript code where I need to skip to next in the for loop....see below:

```
var y = new Array ('1', '2', '3', '4');
for (var x in y) {
   callFunctionOne(y[x]);
   while (condition){
       condition = callFunctionTwo(y[x]);
       //now want to move to the next item so 
       // invoke callFunctionTwo() again...
   }
}
```

Wanted to keep it simple so syntax may be error free.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `continue`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. Also, don't use `for...in` to iterate over arrays.

Comment: I think they meant `break` the while loop and immediately `continue` the *for* loop.  If there's nothing *after* the while, like in your sample, you could just use `break;`

Comment: You can label lots of things in JavaScript, including loops. Combine `continue` and `break` with labels for amazing results!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Don't iterate over arrays using `for...in`. That syntax is for iterating over the properties of an object, which isn't what you're after.

As for your actual question, you can use the `continue`:

```
var y = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (y[i] == 2) {
        continue;
    }

    console.log(y[i]);
}
```

This will print:

```
1
3
4
```

---

Actually, it looks like you want to break out of the `while` loop. You can use `break` for that:

```
while (condition){
    condition = callFunctionTwo(y[x]);
    break;
}
```

Take a look at [`do...while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) loops as well.

Comment: Thank Blender. This will actually help.

Comment: I feel a bit unhappy about this being the only and highly upvoted answer to the question.

In my personal opinion using `for..of` would be a much better alternative, as it is a more reliable and modern way of iterating over the loop while retaining the capability of skipping or canceling the cycle.